# Google Colab GPU speed-up works with 2.x, but not with 1.x

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

In https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb, which I assume is an official demonstration of GPU speed-up by Google, if I follow the steps, the GPU speed-up (around 60 times faster than with CPU) using Tensorflow 2.x works. However, if I want to use version 1.15 like in https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12dduH7y0GPztxSM0AFlfpjj8FU5x8YSv (the only change compared to the notebook from the first link is getting rid of "%tensorflow_version 2.x" both times), `tf.test.gpu_device_name()` returns the string `/device:GPU:0` but there is no speed-up. I would really love to use the a Tensorflow version between 1.5 and 1.15 though, as the code I want to run uses functions removed in Tensorflow 2.x. Does anyone know how to use Tensorflow 1.x while still getting the GPU speed-up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your notebook your code is not executed actually, since you didn't called `session.run()` nor `tf.enable_eager_execution()`.

Add `tf.enable_eager_execution()` at the top of your code and you'll see the real difference between cpu and gpu times.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I confirmed that what you say is true when I use `tf.enable_eager_execution()`. Do you know why with tf 2.x one needs neither `session.run()` nor `tf.enable_eager_execution()` for the speed-up to kick in but with 1.x it does?

Comment: @DeapSoup in tf2, eager execution is enabled by default and there is no more a session concept. If you do not enable eager execution in tf v1.x, you eventually end up calling `session.run` in your code to get network output.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much